# Doctrine - The referenced column name 'id' has to be a primary key column on the target entity class

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, orm

I have problem with validation and schema creation, error log is:

```
[Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'App\Api\Entity\User' mapping is invalid:
* The referenced column name 'id' has to be a primary key column on the target entity class 'App\Acme\Entity\User\BaseUser'.
* The join columns of the association 'createdBy' have to match to ALL identifier columns of the target entity 'App\Acme\Entity\User\BaseUser', however '' are missing.
* The referenced column name 'id' has to be a primary key column on the target entity class 'App\Acme\Entity\User\BaseUser'.
* The join columns of the association 'modifiedBy' have to match to ALL identifier columns of the target entity 'App\Acme\Entity\User\BaseUser', however '' are missing.
```

I am using Symfony 4, and I have problem with inheritance

**src/Acme/Entity/Base/BaseUser.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Acme\Entity\User;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 * @UniqueEntity("email")
 * Class Document
 */
class BaseUser implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
/**
 * @var int The id
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @var BaseUser
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Acme\Entity\User\BaseUser")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="created_by", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $createdBy;

/**
 * @var BaseUser
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\App\Acme\Entity\User\BaseUser")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="modified_by", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $modifiedBy;

public function __construct( BaseUser $user)
{
    $this->createdBy    = $user;
    $this->modifiedBy   = $user;
}



/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getId(): int
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @param int $id
 */
public function setId(int $id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
}
```

and there is an entity that tries to extend this BaseUser

**src/Api/Entity/Base/User.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Api\Entity;

use App\Acme\Entity\User\BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User extends BaseUser  { ... }
```

the problem is somewhere in

```
/**
 * @var BaseUser
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Acme\Entity\User\BaseUser")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="created_by", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $createdBy;

/**
 * @var BaseUser
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\App\Acme\Entity\User\BaseUser")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="modified_by", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $modifiedBy;
```

as I delete them, all works fine.

My mapping file config/packages/doctrine.yaml

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    # With Symfony 3.3, remove the `resolve:` prefix
    url: '%env(DATABASE_URL)%'
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
    auto_mapping: true
    mappings:
        Api:
            is_bundle: false
            type: annotation
            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Api/Entity'
            prefix: 'App\Api\Entity\'
            alias: Api
        Acme:
            is_bundle: false
            type: annotation
            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Acme/Entity'
            prefix: 'App\Acme\Entity\'
            alias: Acme
```

Can you help please?

Comment: Your id has to be in your final class, not in a base class (abstract or model)

Comment: @pbenard i don't think so, I moved id with annotation to src/Api/Entity/Base/User.php problem persists. Id in base class works, problem is in the $createdBy and $modifiedBy

Comment: have you try make the reference to your final class instead base class?

Comment: i've just tried that, when I put 
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\App\Api\Entity\User")
it's ok, but thats not good, because whole Acme namespace should be independent on Api class, there should be no references to code in Api namespace.

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this @xrep?  I have the same problem at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

change to

```
 /**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;
```

check your targetEntity Namespace. where is bundle...portion [Symfony Bundle Name Doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/best_practices.html#bundle-name)

```
/**
* @var BaseUser
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="yourBaseUser")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="created_by", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
protected $createdBy;

/**
* @var BaseUser
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="yourBaseUser")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="modified_by", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
protected $modifiedBy;
```

Comment: Symfony 4 doesn't recommend "...Bundle" directory structure. But, same problem is also in Symfony3 with "...Bundle" directory structure